# How to properly embed Qt 5.15 localizations in an iOS application

Tags: c++, ios, qt, qml, qmake

Qt 5.15 introduces (at least I believe it is new to 5.15) .ts files, to allow for properly handling multi-locale text in an application. I'm updating an iOS Qt app from 5.X, where X knows nothing about .ts files. On startup, I'm getting a warning that indicates that there is an app-specific translation set (which is true), but that there is no translation for Qt's own text (things like warning text and dialog prompts). The documentation says, that these translations are in the Qt5 source directory (currently usually /tqtc-qt5) in the qtttranslations folder. Thus sayeth this doc https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/ios-platform-notes.html#application-assets. Examples show only app-unique text translations, not Qt's "built-in" text. So real quick, I'm going list my assumptions, so that they can be corrected or confirmed.

1. Qt has always had embedded text of its own, but 5.15 introduces a way to ensure that your multi-locale ready app has all the correctly translated "built-in" text available.
2. Only the app-writer knows what modules they are using, so it is the app-writer's responsibility to specify which set of translations are added to the app's resources for handling different locales. (per this document - https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qmake-variable-reference.html#translations)
3. According to the above two docs, for example, if I use basic Qt functionality and QML, AND I have a single app with tier-one language support for, say, English, German, and French, it appears that my app's .pro file should include something like

   ```
   TRANSLATIONS += <path_to_qt5>/qttranslations/qtbase_en.ts 
   TRANSLATIONS += <path_to_qt5>/qttranslations/qtbase_de.ts 
   TRANSLATIONS += <path_to_qt5>/qttranslations/qtbase_fr.ts 
   TRANSLATIONS += <path_to_qt5>/qttranslations/qtdeclarative_en.ts 
   TRANSLATIONS += <path_to_qt5>/qttranslations/qtdeclarative_de.ts 
   TRANSLATIONS += <path_to_qt5>/qttranslations/qtdeclarative_fr.ts

   CONFIG += lrelease embed_translations
   ```

I've traced though the Qt source in the debugger to the point where it is complaining about the missing translations. It is looking for qt*_*.qm, where the first wildcard is your module ("base", "declarative", etc) and the second is your two-letter language code. So, should I be explicitly adding .qm files as resources in my iOS bundle, or is `TRANSLATIONS += foo_ln.ts` implicitly doing this embedding in response to `CONFIG += lrelease embed_translations`. One things is certain: right now, my naive porting of an older .pro file does nothing with respect the `TRANSLATIONS` property AND Qt is cranky about the missing .qm files in my bundle. It's a warning, not a critical fail, so I assume in a pinch, it would put up US english text, which seems to be the baseline for translations and is embedded in the source (not the bundle) by default. Do my example additions to the .pro file in point 3 above seem sufficient, or is there more to do? Or is there less to do? Is there a .pro directive that I've missed in the docs that says "do the right thing with international translations of Qt-inherent strings"? There is in a addition to the listed .ts files a "qt_*.ts" file set. Is this just everything whether I need it or not, for lazy people who don't care about lugging around a few extra strings? Finally, there is also `EXTRA_TRANSLATIONS` which is like `TRANSLATIONS`, only it does not go through the `lupdate` during the build. Now I'm pretty unclear on the function of `lupdate` relative to `lrelease`, but is it the case that one is for "stock" Qt strings, and the other for App-specific translations (because they may be "updated" due to changes during development)? The semantics just don't make sense to me right now, nor do my responsibilities to handle these matters in the "right" way.

Answer (score 0):

I'd like to answer my own question because it turns out many of the above assumptions were just wrong, and it took deeper dives into the source code and the debugger to get my head straight, but now I have Wisdom. The documents I was reading was about how to include raw translation files "(.ts files)" into an app being built with `qmake`. As is typical with `Qt`, building with `qmake` or `Qt Creator` solves most of your problems automatically, with your part being to provide only the small amount of specification needed to execute your app. The app I'm working on however is monstrously huge, old, and overly-complicated, so I spend a lot of time hunting down the most obscure `Qt` and `CMake` features to cobble this Frankenstein's monster of an app together. The problem I was trying to solve is simply providing to `Qt` its own text localization files for a multi-locale app. The app-specific ones were fine, but Qt was wagging its finger at me and complaining that it couldn't find its own. So the .ts files it turns out are not a thing for this kind of task - they are simply part of the pipeline of getting data from a translation house in a consumable form. During `Qt`'s own configure and build (yes we build `Qt` from source), it handles the compiling of raw .ts files into .qm files, suitable for use by the framework's translator objects. Those are all just sitting in `qtbase/translations` ready to be integrated into the app installation. The problem was that we (the group who developed this app long ago and which I am now reviving) didn't handle the `iOS` case. This is a special case that requires some choices. You can put translation files in the app's bundle at a specific path, you can home-brew some exotic URL resolution whereby you feed the translator the contents of the .qm files on demand, or you can compile them all into a .qrc file and position them in your resource tree. That last is what we did with the app-specific translations, so I mimicked it for `Qt`'s, filtering the total set of .qm files for the modules we use and for the locales in our tier-one localization target languages. This involved a complicated python script, and a few extra lines of Cmake, including one very elusive one (`QINIT_RESOURCES`) that gated everything until I realized it was needed for this platform. I'm only wrapping this up, so if anyone else is confused enough to find this question, that there are some general comments to set things straight.